# Testing a before filter in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I seem to be stuck. I am trying to shore up some rspec testing and want to make sure the the correct before_filter methods are getting called for controllers. However, I am getting feedback saying the method never gets called.

The error:

```
Failure/Error: expect(controller).to receive(:authorize)
   (#<UsersController:0x007fca2fd27110>).authorize(*(any args))
       expected: 1 time with any arguments
       received: 0 times with any arguments
```

The spec:

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe UsersController, :type => :controller do
  let(:school){ FactoryGirl.create :school }
  let(:user){ FactoryGirl.create :teacher}
  before(:each){
    allow(controller).to receive(:current_user).and_return(user)
    school.teachers << user
  }

  context "Get #show" do
    before(:each){ get :show, school_id: school.id, id: user.id }
    it "responds successfully with an HTTP 200 status code" do
      expect(controller).to receive(:authorize)
      expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
    end

    it "renders the show template" do
      expect(response).to render_template("show")
    end
  end
end
```

The controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authorize

  def show
    @user = User.find_by_id params[:id]
    @school = @user.school
    @coordinators = @school.coordinators
    @teachers = @school.teachers
    @speducators = @school.speducators
    @students = @school.students
  end
end
```

Manual testing shows that before is being called, and when I put a p in the authorize method it is called when I run the test, any thoughts on where the test is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set method expectation *before* actual call, so your test should look like:

```
context "Get #show" do
  subject { get :show, school_id: school.id, id: user.id }

  it "calls +authorize+ befor action" do
    expect(controller).to receive(:authorize)
    subject
  end
end
```

Check the documentation https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks#message-expectations

Comment: I am unfamiliar with subject. Am I supposed to be using it instead of before blocks?

Comment: @AdamCooper86. Yes, but you have to call `subject` manually in every test case in order to make GET request. `before` hook would be ran automatically. Documentation for `subject` semantics - https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-4/docs/subject/explicit-subject